# Dropdown menu failing to dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, web

I'm trying to add a dropdown menu to my website. At first when I used the code everything worked perfectly, but then I must have accidentally typed something because now it doesn't work!

Can anyone help me resolve this?
This is the code for the dropdown menu I'm using:

```
$(function(){ 
  $("item").click(
    function(){ 
      $("submenu").slidetoggle(500); 
    }
  ); 
});
```

Comment: I incorporated the code from the comment.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have missed the **#** if it's a reference to id or the **.** if to a class.

Try this..

```
$(function() {
    $("#item").click(function() {
        $("#submenu").slidetoggle(500);
    });
});
```

or this..

```
$(function() {
    $(".item").click(function() {
        $("#submenu").slidetoggle(500);
    });
});
```

or this...

```
$(function() {
    $(".item").click(function() {
        $(".submenu").slidetoggle(500);
    });
});
```